# jQuery is not validating

Tags: jquery

My jQuery is not validating:

How can I do this correctly?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test-form").validate({
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      customerName: "required",
      emailAddress: {
        required: true,
        // Specify that email should be validated
        // by the built-in "email" rule
        email: true
      },
      plateNumber: {
        required: true
      },
      date: {
        required: true
      },
      time: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      emailAddress: "Please enter a valid email address",
      customerName: "We require your name",
      plateNumber: "Please enter your vehicle's plate number",
      date: "We require the installation date",
      time: "We require your approximate time"
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-UdIMMlVx0HEynClOIFSyOrPggomfhBKJE28LKl8yR3ghkgugPnG6iLfRfHwushZl1MOPSY6TsuBDGPK2X4zYKg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="test-form" name="test-form" role="form" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group focused">
    <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-email-83"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group focused">
    <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-circle-08"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" name="customerName" id="customerName" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group focused">
    <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-caps-small"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Plate Number" type="text" name="plateNumber" id="plateNumber" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- <div class="form-group focused">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-building"></i></span>
                      </div>
                      <select 
                        class="form-control" 
                        id="stations"
                        name="station"
                        >
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div> -->

  <div class="form-group focused">
    <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-bulb-61"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Date" type="date" name="date" id="date" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group focused">
    <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-watch-time"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Time" type="time" name="time" id="time" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row my-4">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="custom-control custom-control-alternative custom-checkbox">
        <input class="custom-control-input" id="customCheckRegister" type="checkbox">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheckRegister"><span>I agree with the <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4" id="submit-form">Submit your schedule</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant jQuery and validator files

Comment: Seems to work, especially if I change email to emailAddress in the validator and add the validation script and jQuery files

Comment: it works fine, if it doesn't work for you, I assume you have js error or a conflict in your code or something like that.

Comment: I will check on it as soon as I get to a PC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library, but I suggest you to name the key in the rules object like the attributes name of your input tags (according to documentation)

Comment: Please give examples of what you mean. Seems the IDs match

Comment: The email input name is "emailAddress", and the validation rule is "email", so maybe for only 1 field, the library doesn't work properly

Comment: But for the rest it did. I think OP forgot to include the script files